# Exporting multi-record set data

Tags: export, multi-record

Hi I am trying to export data held in a multi-record set. A end users would prefer to do this through the Civi interface rather than on the back-end database

The multi-value import link is buried in the help tips pop up... hoping the export is exists and is just similarly buried

We using v4.6.2

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8938/how-do-you-export-a-multi-record-set

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, at this time (CiviCRM 4.7.13) it's not possible to export multi-record custom fields through the CiviCRM interface.

This question: [How do you export a multi record set?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8938/how-do-you-export-a-multi-record-set) suggests an alternate method that may work, but it would take someone experienced at writing custom CiviReports.

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8938/how-do-you-export-a-multi-record-set suggests exporting in some manner is now possible via CiviReports

Comment: jon - do you want to add my comment to your answer, then i will +1 it and keep SE happy(ier)

Comment: @petednz-fuzion It could also be its own separate answer!  I'll do as you suggest - but I'll note that I tried to do as it said and it's not trivial, even a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running CiviCRM on a Drupal instance, I've managed to export a multi-value field with the Drupal Views and Views Export modules.