# How do you export a multi record set?

Tags: export

On CiviContact we have a number of custom fields set up as multi-record sets.
Any ideas on how these can be exported?

The import to a multi-record set is hidden on the main import page > tooltips pop up has a link at the end of the help notes which takes you to the import page.  Is the export function similarly hidden...

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any hidden export pages, but if you can talk the data into appearing in a report then you can export as CSV from there. We've created a few custom reports to allow this on our multi-record custom data.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! Yes I was having a brain dead day - reporting solves the non-export option fro multi record sets.  Thank you

Comment: Note that you have to use Contact Summary report and not Contact Detail report - the latter does not have a CSV export option

Comment: Warning! Depending on the report, it may not display all the records in the multi record set — it may choose one, arbitrarily, for each contact. For example, the Flexible Contact Report included with Fuzion's Extended Reports extension can handle multi-record custom fields, but make sure you set your filters so that the one record displayed on each line is the one you want. Or choose "group by Contact ID" so they'll be concatenated.

Comment: Andrew - are you able to share an example of custom reports with multi-record custom data?

Comment: Sure: https://gist.github.com/bhahumanists/98a6a154a394f008a86fec55d855f3ae. I don't know how compliant it is with best practices these days

Comment: To @NoahMiller, thanks for the tip, but how / where do you set the "set your filters so that the one record displayed on each line is the one you want"? I've created an extended report, but cannot find the option. I am trying to create a report, for a specific contact that will list all entries of a custom field set (multiple records). Thank you

Answer (score 3):

There’s a custom search available called ‘Custom Group Multiple Values Listing’ that allows you to search and export multi value fields –

Search > Custom Searches > Custom Group Multiple Values Listing